# What is the best way to communicate that your constructor has failed in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, constructor

In C# I want to communicate to the calling method that the parameters passed to an object have caused its instantiation to fail.

```
// okay
Banana banana1 = new Banana("green");

// fail
Banana banana2 = new Banana("red");
```

Throw an exception? If so how?

Comment: Why should that fail? http://images.google.com/images?q=red+banana

Comment: @Rob Taking pedantry to new levels! ROFL!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
throw new ArgumentException("Reason", "param name");
```

Comment: +1 - just remember that it may be more appropriate to throw one the derived exceptions such as ArgumentNullException or ArgumentOutOfRangeException, or a similarly purposed exception such as FormatException.

Answer (score 12):

A lot (all?) of the answers are saying to throw an exception, but I'm sure I've seen official statements from the framework design team advising against throwing exceptions from constructors.

Note that the classes in the .NET framework that behave similarly to your "Banana" example (where only certain values are appropriate to instantiate the object with) don't use constructors, but instead use static factory methods. For example, [System.Net.WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) has no public constructor, and instead uses a static [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.create.aspx) method which can raise an exception if the supplied string is not a valid URI. *With some exceptions - see my update below.*

So for your code I would change Banana's constructor to protected, and introduce a method like this:

```
public static Banana Create(string color) 
{
    if (color != "green" && color != "yellow")
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Color must be 'green' or 'yellow'", 
            "color");
    }
    return new Banana(color);
}
```

**Update**

Ok, it seems like it's not a *bad* idea to throw exceptions from a constructor. In fact, System.IO.FileStream does just that if you pass an invalid filename to its constructor. I guess the idea of using a static factory method is just one way of being more explicit about how you're creating the instance (for example, if the method above were called "FromColor").

Comment: It is not a bad idea to throw an exception from a constructor. There is no possible reason or justification for that viewpoint. If it were a guideline there would be an FxCop rule for it, and there isn't.

Comment: It uses a static method because WebRequest is abstract. It uses the parameter to decide whether to create an HttpWebRequest or a FileWebRequest.

Comment: You're probably thinking of a *static* constructor from which it isn't a good idea to throw an exception as static constructors are not retriable and it makes the type unusable. However this is not a problem with *instance* constructors.

Comment: Ah WebRequest might have been a bad example then. I'm sure I've seen other examples for just this reason. Is there a class in the BCL that might throw an exception from its ctor?

Comment: FileStream! It throws an ArgumentException in its constructor if you pass in an invalid path. I will amend my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Matt-Even in your example, if the Banana() constructor had an error, shouldn't that throw an exception to your static Create() classfactory method?

Comment: I dunno, John. I would normally code a ctor such that it couldn't throw an error. Guard against it in other ways. The "banana/colour" example is pretty contrived - in that case I'd have a BananaColor enum and pass that in so only valid values are possible.

Comment: You could still have invalid values with an enum, e.g. enum BananaColor { Yellow, Green }; BananaColor invalid = (BananaColor)123; Enums aren't properly type-safe so you still need to check for invalid values and throw.

Comment: But, Matt, like you said, this example is contrived.  But if inside your constructor, there was an error, for what ever reason.  The only other way I can see to communicate that error might be an 'IsValid' property on the object ... which I don't think is as elegant as an exception (IMHO).

Comment: BTW- +1 for your openness to discuss this, and keep the comment conversation going.

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't want to delete the question even if it's not correct. I still think it brings another viewpoint to the conversation. I like factory methods for this sort of thing, but this post has "brought me around" to exceptions from ctors.

Comment: +1 Your train of thought and the back/forth in the discussion for this answer are priceless.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The most accepted solution is to throw an exception.  To prove this, open reflector and have a look at most of the classes from the BCL and the exceptions that they can throw on construction.

As an example. List(IEnumerable collection) will throw an exception if collection is null.  A perfectly valid way of communicating errors to the caller.

Comment: "The most accepted solution is to throw an exception", I'd even question if any other strategy makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If your constructor fails, you should throw an exception.  By defenition, Constructors do not return values, so you cant return, say, an error code.

```
public class Banana 
{
    public Banana(string color)
    {
        if ( color == "red" )
          throw new SomeException("intialization failed, red is an invalid color");

    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////     
try
{
    Banana banana1 = new Banana("green");
    banana1.whatever();
}
catch( SomeException error )
{
    // do something
}
finally
{
    // always do  this stuff
}
```

Comment: The BCL includes ArgumentException for exactly this.  Unless there's a damn good reason, you should stick to the base exceptions, as that's what people are used to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want ArgumentException...